# Python Pandas Timestamp Subtraction vs. Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am having an odd issue when subtracting Timestamps in pandas (version 15.2) on Python 3.4

Incorrect

```
y = pd.Timestamp('2015-04-14 00:00:00')
z = pd.Timestamp('2015-04-14 00:01:01')
np.timedelta64(z-y)
>>>numpy.timedelta64(1000000,'us')
```

Correct

```
w = np.datetime64(y)
x = np.datetime64(z)
np.timedelta64(x-w)
>>>numpy.timedelta64(61000000,'us')
```

Correct

```
y = np.datetime64('2015-04-14 00:00:00')
z = np.datetime64('2015-04-14 00:01:01')
np.timedelta64(z-y)
>>>numpy.timedelta64(61,'s')
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: This works correctly for me on pandas 0.16.0 and numpy '1.9.2rc1', what version numpy are you using and can you upgrade your pandas?

Comment: Strange. I recently updated Anaconda (last night). numpy version 1.9.2 and pandas version 0.15.2.

Comment: I've also restarted the kernel in jupyter, and it is persistent. PyCharm has the same issue, so it's not editor/IDE related.

Comment: Confirmed that Pandas v0.16.0 works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with Pandas 0.15.2. Upgrading to 0.16.0 solves the issue.